# update-grub fails /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-vista

The HD of my computer (/dev/sda) has 3 partitions (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sda3), each containing a copy of Windows Vista Ultimate (restored from a Clonezilla partition image).

Using an Ubuntu LiveCD (15.04), I successfully installed Grub2 in the MBR of the HD using the following commands:

```
#sudo su
#mkdir /mnt/sda1
#mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
#grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sda1 /dev/sda
"Installation finished. No error reported."
```

Running os-prober output the following:

```
#os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows Vista (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda2:Windows Vista (loader):Windows1:chain
/dev/sda3:Windows Vista (loader):Windows2:chain
```

However, when I attempt to run update-grub (to generate a grub.cfg file), I receive the following error:

```
#update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can get update-grub to work using the Ubuntu LiveCD?  If possible I would really like to avoid building my grub.cfg file completely from scratch.

Any and all help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use boot-repair - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair